# Discrepancies in ggplot2 output in DataCamp and Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm finding apparent discrepancies between the output in the Datacamp R plot output and the Rstudio plots output.

On DataCamp the following code provides a coloured geom_freqpoly() while in Rstudio it is left to default of black. 
I have tried moving the `col=cyl` outside of the `aes()` but all to no avail

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, col= cyl)) +
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 1, position = "identity")
```

I am using the latest version of 64 bit R on windows 10. 
Has anyone else experienced similar problems or could explain why this is not working?

Comment: I don't know about DataCamp, but you're right, the line is black. (Ubuntu 18.04 here.) `aes(mpg, colour = factor(cyl))` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that in the Datacamp environment `cyl` is a `factor`variable in the mtcars dataset and in your RStudio environment it is a `numeric`variable. 
This should give you the intended result:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, col= as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 1, position = "identity")
```

I simply converted the `cyl` variable to a factor. You can check if `class(mtcars$cyl)` is `factor` in your RStudio environment.

Comment: Not character, `class(mtcars$cyl)` returns `[1] "numeric"`. Upvote, you beat me by a few seconds.